# Costmap not inflating all obstacles

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Sometimes my local costmap does not inflate all obstacles. It marks everything that it should as LETHAL, but then doesn't mark some of the cells around the lethal cells. Picture attached for reference.

[image: image description]

Might this be a bug in the inflation_layer? I've used dynamic_reconfigure to play with my costmap settings and nothing has helped it.

ROS Indigo standard navigation stack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233440/costmap-not-inflating-all-obstacles/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2016-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) on 2016-05-02**:
Can you post the YAML files you used to configure the costmaps, as well as the relevant launch files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

The problem was the ordering of the plugins. If the inflation_layer plugin gets loaded before the obstacle_layer plugin, you get the above behavior. Loading the obstacle layer first solves this problem.

---

Originally posted by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) with karma: 255 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2